# React useEffect hook dispatch actions on chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

First of all i am new to react hooks. hence please bear if it's silly.

So, i want to dispatch actions one after another in useEffect hook (on Load).

Also my second dispatch needs data from first dispatch.

Here is what i have written which is not working.

```
const userData = useSelector((state) => state.user.data);
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(fetchUser("someUserId")).then(() => {
      dispatch(fetchProjects("someUserId", userData.settings.startDate));
   });
}, []); // on load
```

In the above code, userData.settings is fetched from first dispatch. When i run the code i get an error saying userData.settings is not defined.

Please let me know, what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you get for `console.log(userData.settings);` just after the `useSelector(..`?

Comment: I get null. Userdata itself is null

Comment: Please show some code about `useSelector`.  Whether there is `settings` on `userData` or not, it depends on `useSelector`